# what kind of eclipse project for model of MVC?

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller, model

For building a Java EE MVC application, I want to keep the M (Model) of it in a separate project. What kind of eclipse project should be used for M (Model)?

I think a **Dynamic Web Project** would be used for both V (View) and C (Controller) but dont know what to use for the M (Model) part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have three projects:

- View: Web Application Project.
- Controller: Java Project, you should have your main settings (xml files, base classes, etc) in this project.
- Model: Java Project, you should have your DAOs, Entities, Classes for data proccesing, etc.

Your Controller Project and Model Project should be Jar Files, you just need to add them to your View Project, I recommend you to use maven to build each project. I think this is a good way to support your MVC project.

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.

Comment: What about the dependencies among these 3 projects?

Comment: You can add the necessary dependencies to each project, for example, if you use hibernate you could add hibernate dependencies only to the Model project. After that your Model project and Controller project could be dependencies of Web Application Project. Maven is good for this.

Answer (score 1):

All models, views and controller should typically be in the same mvc project, perhaps in different packages for clarity. But you should not have models in other project. If you do, you may want to add the corresponding jar is main projects classpatth, import models and use them.

So create a normal library project which has your models and import it to your Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: Normal Library project means Java project? What about the **Utility Project** under Java EE in eclipse? What is that used for?